# Get width and height of ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `viewpager` in my layout:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"></ListView>

<CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Now I want to get the actually width and height of the `ViewPager`:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {
    public MyBookView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Log.d("pager","width:" + getWidth() + "mwidth:" + getMeasuredWidth());
    }
}
```

While the `width` and `mwidth` is always `0`.

What's the problem?

Comment: you could try customVeiwPager.postDelayed(new Runnable)

Comment: How can this help with getting the dimensions of the `ViewPager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait to get the width and height after `onMeasure()` is called. The view hasn't gone through its layout lifecycle yet.